# Looking for a very precise tx/rx circuit module to calculate distance

Tags: microcontroller, robotics, distance, tracking

Thanks for helping. I'm looking for a system that will help me find exact distance between a transmitter and receiver at a frequency of milli seconds, in distance accuracy of milli meters.

I want to avoid environmental factors, reflections or line of sight issues. My initial idea is to have a transmitter pulsating at 30 msec. Use the time taken between signals received to calculate the exact distance. Initially I am looking for a range of 20 m. But in future I would like to explore the idea of upto 1000m.

I think GPS wouldn't work, I am open to any modulation techniques. Are there any pre existing modules?

Comment: Pre-existing technique is called "radar". Most recently, look into laser rangefinder. Did you research these techniques?

Comment: BTW one transmitter repeating signals at some interval is not going to give you a range of any kind unless you have some kind of TOF clock synchronization between the two devices.  At millimeter resolution scales clock drift can become a problem.

Comment: Are you allowed to use a corner reflector? NASA had the lunar lander astronauts leave a panel of such optically-square mirrors on the moon, for improved distance measuring.

Comment: I'm new to all this and these are excellent head ways for me to go research more. Thanks!

Comment: Why are syncho tx rx system are hard to design? When we can have miniature remote controlled robotics.

Comment: To solve the clock synchronization issue. The system could work on the principal that receiver syncs at the initial beat when the tx is at 0m distance, now we know the frequency of transmission, which receiver can add to the initial clock sync. Hence, it wouldn't need to have tof. Could that work?

Comment: It may be a language issue, but what you are describing is TOF.  As you say start with both devices next to each other and they synch their pulse clocks.  As they separate the time it takes the EM wave to reach the other device increases, roughly 1ns per 30cm (that gives you an idea of the scale we're talking about).  Assuming the clocks have not drifted apart, then the receiving device can calculate the -radial- distance from the the transmitter by determining how many nanoseconds have elapsed between its clock and the received clock.  Simple concept, yes, implementation not so much.

Comment: regarding the remote control issue, that's really a completely different topic.  For one thing the data rates in comparison to the carrier frequency are relatively low (there's a difference between the bit rate and symbol/baud rate in "modern" digital RF communication systems), and most robotics systems don't work on nanosecond timescales (insofar as physical movement is concerned).

Comment: Very insightful. You are amazing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gosh, so does every other RTLS system. (/humor)

Research UWB (ultra wideband) ranging if you want off the shelf modules. That's probably going to be your best bet for millimeter grade accuracy.

There are of course other systems such as laser TOF/interforemetry, however they are line of sight (unless you use mirrors) and don't go through most objects.

Using RF triangulation techniques can be done, however multipath issues are problematic (hence the UWB push).

It all depends on your environment (which you say very little about).

Comment: Why are syncho tx rx system are hard to design? When we can have miniature remote controlled robotics.

Comment: Is there a way I can chat or message to you? I believe this site doesn't have that option.

Comment: There is chat facility, but you have to have a reputation of 20+ to to be able to write in one, yet viewing public conversations is no problem (yes, it's frustrating, but it's not really SE's primary goal).  The downsides to chat is that it can be hours between responses (for example I'll be unavailable most of tomorrow).